# jQuery and CSS - Having images behind each other in slider and how to repeat my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a simple slider, but I'm stuck.

I want the images to be placed behind each other but without position: absolute, because the images will ignore the max-width of the container.

Secondly, how can I repeat my function slideplay?

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/pweyGq

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var img1 = $(".image-holder img:first-child");
  var img2 = $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(2)");
  var img3 = $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(3)");
  var img4 = $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(4)");

  /*var img1_child = $(".image-holder-small img:first-child");
  var img2_child = $(".image-holder-small img:nth-of-type(2)");
  var img3_child = $(".image-holder-small img:nth-of-type(3)");
  var img4_child = $(".image-holder-small img:nth-of-type(4)");*/

  var images = [img1, img2, img3, img4];

  var repeat = true;

  function sliderplay(a, b, c, d) {
    img1.fadeTo('slow', 1);
    img1.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
    img2.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    img2.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
    img3.delay(10000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    img3.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
    img4.delay(15000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    img4.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
  }


  sliderplay(img1, img2, img3, img4);


});
```

```css
.slide {
  margin: 50px;
}


/* Bullet Points*/

.bullet-points a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Big images*/

.image-holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="image-holder">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" style="display: none;">
          <img src="https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg" style="display: none;">
          <img src="http://dreamicus.com/data/image/image-06.jpg" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <div class="bullet-points">
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css could be fixed by:

```
.image-holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position:absolute;
}
```

And your loop can be created by:

```
setInterval(function () {
  sliderplay(img1, img2, img3, img4);
}, 1000);
```

You can play around with it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var img1 = $(".image-holder img:first-child");
  var img2 = $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(2)");
  var img3 = $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(3)");
  var img4 = $(".image-holder img:nth-of-type(4)");

  /*var img1_child = $(".image-holder-small img:first-child");
  var img2_child = $(".image-holder-small img:nth-of-type(2)");
  var img3_child = $(".image-holder-small img:nth-of-type(3)");
  var img4_child = $(".image-holder-small img:nth-of-type(4)");*/

  var images = [img1, img2, img3, img4];

  var repeat = true;

  function sliderplay(a, b, c, d) {
    img1.fadeTo('slow', 1);
    img1.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
    img2.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    img2.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
    img3.delay(10000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    img3.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
    img4.delay(15000).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    img4.delay(5000).fadeTo('slow', 0);
    
  }
  
  
setInterval(function () {
  sliderplay(img1, img2, img3, img4);
}, 1000);

  
 


});
```

```css
.slide {
  margin: 50px;
}


/* Bullet Points*/

.bullet-points a {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Big images*/

.image-holder {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="image-holder">
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" style="display: none;">
          <img src="https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg" style="display: none;">
          <img src="http://dreamicus.com/data/image/image-06.jpg" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <div class="bullet-points">
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
          <a href="_self">&bull;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know how I can loop my sliderplay function?

Comment: Working on that aswell

Comment: Thank you. I expanded my slider and added some text on the right side which also should be changed together with the slider image. Not sure if this is relevant when looping the function. https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/owZOOm

Comment: Take a look now.

Comment: My bad it messes up some timings. Looks kinda weird. But if you probably set the right timings it should work. Hope that helps at least a bit